# How do I check if file exists in Makefile so I can delete it?

Tags: makefile

In the clean section of my `Makefile` I am trying to check if the file exists before deleting permanently. I use this code but I receive errors.

What's wrong with it?

```sh
 if [ -a myApp ]
 then
     rm myApp
 fi
```

I get this error message

```sh
 if [ -a myApp ]
 /bin/sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")
 make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

Comment: Is myApp a variable or an actual filename?

Comment: myApp is for myApplication i.e. the filename by the build process.

Comment: If you just want to avoid make stopping if the file does not exist, `rm -rf myApp` could be an alternative. Or preceding the command with a dash (`-rm myApp`) to make make ignore the error from rm (it will however print an ugly message).

Comment: Your problem was that make treats each line in a rule as a separate command and sends them individually to the shell.  It's like running just  `if [ -a myApp ]' on its own.  If you get this error you either need a solution which joins the lines into one (using \) or which ends up with each line independent of the other.  There are now several of these below.

Comment: Where can I learn about the options like "-a". I couldn't find it in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html ?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

The second top answer mentions `ifeq`, however, it fails to mention that this `ifeq` must be at the same indentation level in the makefile as the name of the target, e.g., to download a file only if it doesn't currently exist, the following code could be used:

```Makefile
download:
ifeq (,$(wildcard ./glob.c))
    curl … -o glob.c
endif

# THIS DOES NOT WORK!
download:
    ifeq (,$(wildcard ./glob.c))
        curl … -o glob.c
    endif
```

Comment: did not work until I added backslash `\` after if fi

Comment: This answer will be a bit weird;  the file check happens when the makefile is processed but the action will happen later when the target is built by make.  If you delete the file in the meantime then the file won't be created.  I have put in an edit to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks much! This point was not clear from reading the manual.

Answer (score 259):

It's strange to see so many people using shell scripting for this. I was looking for a way to use native makefile syntax, because I'm writing this outside of any target. You can use the `wildcard` function to check if file exists:

```Makefile
 ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
     SHELL := /opt/local/bin/bash
     OS_X  := true
 else ifneq (,$(wildcard /etc/redhat-release))
     OS_RHEL := true
 else
     OS_DEB  := true
     SHELL := /bin/bash
 endif
```

**See also:**

- [GNU make documentation: wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html)

**Update**:

I found a way which I really like:

```Makefile
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(PATH_TO_FILE))","")
    FILE_EXISTS = 1
else
    FILE_EXISTS = 0
endif
```

Comment: I've got actually alternative variant recently. I'm discovering package managers with this `yum := $(shell { type yum; } 2>/dev/null)` and with `ifdef` you can check if variable empty or not, and then set something like `RHEL:=true`

Comment: tried this, but I just keep getting ```Makefile:133: *** unterminated call to function `wildcard': missing `)'.  Stop.```

Comment: @arsenbonbon Your comment really helps. Appreciated.

Comment: @Ant6n You might be missing a parentheses. Please check.

Comment: This fails if $(PATH_TO_FILE) evaluates to a filename containing parentheses.

Comment: Great use of wildcard, so it can be done with makefile itself. Neat :)

Comment: Helps to also understand what `$(wildcard pattern)` actually does. [See link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make this work within a make rule (when "indented")?

Comment: More concise: `FILE_EXISTS := $(or $(and $(wildcard $(PATH_TO_FILE)),1),0)`

Comment: It's worth noting if you're running on Windows under cygwin, using wildcard in this manner does a case sensitive match on the filename, so if the file exists but with different case than the path it won't be found. There doesn't seem to be any way to override this behaviour within the makefile.

Comment: `directives only work if they're not indented` with **tabs**. Plus, they run at makefile parsing stage, not in "runtime" (target execution) stage.

Comment: Running the latter example, I'm getting `/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"",""'`

Answer (score 81):

The problem is when you split your command over multiple lines.  So, you can either use the `\` at the end of lines for continuation as above or you can get everything on one line with the `&&` operator in bash.

Then you can use a `test` command to test if the file does exist, e.g.:

```sh
test -f myApp && echo File does exist
```

> `-f file`       True if file exists and is a regular file.

> `-s file`       True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.

or does not:

```sh
test -f myApp || echo File does not exist
test ! -f myApp && echo File does not exist
```

The `test` is equivalent to `[` command.

```sh
[ -f myApp ] && rm myApp   # remove myApp if it exists
```

and it would work as in your original example.

See: `help [` or `help test` for further syntax.

Comment: I would have upvoted, but you did not warn that `-s` is a special case for `exists and has a size greater than zero`. The question as written is size-agnostic, so existence should be checked using `test -e` for a file or `-d` for a directory. Empty files can be especially useful as (for want of a better term) indicators/sentinels, which might be quite relevant for `make`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Changed `-f` by default, as it's more common to use.

Comment: How can I get `test` on Windows?

Comment: This I could get to work on one line in make file like this:    @ test -f file && echo file exist    -- however I could not get the other examples to work

Comment: In order for this to work you need to add `|| true` at the end so the command return true when file don't exists.

Comment: This answer should be upvoted as it is easy, simple, one-line, and solves the problem.

Comment: @Alexander: No, this relies on OS-specific shell trickery, where the wildcard function is a built-in GNU Make means of achieving the same thing without OS-specific calls.

Comment: I agree with @Alexander - this is a good answer though it needs to be clear this works because it's a one liner using && rather than multiline with if.  I put in an edit to improve it.

Comment: In the "or does not:" section your first echo is wrong, should be "does exist". i.e. Your two echos are the same for opposite cases. (Copy & Paste error I guess)

Comment: @AndrewMackenzie `test -f myApp || CMD`, notice the `||`, so if `-f` will fail - does not exist (`||`), then run the command. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 55):

It may need a backslash on the end of the line for continuation (although perhaps that depends on the version of make):

```sh
if [ -a myApp ] ; \
then \
     rm myApp ; \
fi;
```

Comment: seems to be not a Makefile syntax? http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_7.html

Comment: @holms its a bash syntax. By escaping the new lines it allows it to be handled as a single bash command. By default in `make` a new line would be a new bash command. The major caveat of this, other than the annoyance of having lots of `\ ` at the end of lines is that every command must be terminated with the `;` which would otherwise be implicit in bash.

Comment: The right answer is by @holms. Neither '\' nor wildcard is exactly intended for this purpose. The reason why you would use wildcard is for code clarity. Not only is this method less readable, it's more prone to syntax errors.

Comment: the link @holms provided does not work anymore, use http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals instead

Comment: this is a great answer because it matches what is wrong with what the original questioner did and it will work depending on whether the file exists at the time the target is build rather than at the time the Makefile is started which is what most people would expect and want most of the time.  In a few weird cases the answer from @cnst would be better.

Comment: The original question, and this answer are attacking it at the `inside an action command` phase, whereas the @holms answer is attacking it at the `makefile parsing` phase.  So which answer is best depends on what you need.

Answer (score 38):

Or just put it on one line, as `make` likes it:

```sh
if [ -a myApp ]; then rm myApp; fi;
```

Comment: that's a great answer in this case (and should get upvotes) but won't work so well if the actions were more complex, in which case just switch to using \

Comment: [ -a myApp ] && rm myApp

Comment: ERROR `/bin/sh: 1: [: -a: unexpected operator`

Answer (score 25):

One line solution:

```sh
   [ -f ./myfile ] && echo exists
```

One line solution with error action:

```sh
   [ -f ./myfile ] && echo exists || echo not exists
```

Example used in my `make clean` directives:

```Makefile
clean:
    @[ -f ./myfile ] && rm myfile || true
```

And `make clean` works without error messages!

Comment: just do @rm -f myfile. Because of the "-f" flag, "rm" will exit with 0 regardless of whether the file exists or not.

Comment: Or, `-rm myfile` the lead dash telling make to ignore any error.

Comment: In my case, leaving off the || <error action> caused problems.  Your final example, where you returned true if the file did not exist, addressed this nicely.  Thank you!

Comment: For me path to myfile needs to be with apostrophe('):
`@[ -f 'myfile' ] && rm myfile`

Answer (score 17):

```Makefile
FILE1 = /usr/bin/perl
FILE2 = /nofile

ifeq ($(shell test -e $(FILE1) && echo -n yes),yes)
    RESULT1=$(FILE1) exists.
else
    RESULT1=$(FILE1) does not exist.
endif

ifeq ($(shell test -e $(FILE2) && echo -n yes),yes)
    RESULT2=$(FILE2) exists.
else
    RESULT2=$(FILE2) does not exist.
endif

all:
    @echo $(RESULT1)
    @echo $(RESULT2)
```

execution results:

```Makefile
bash> make
/usr/bin/perl exists.
/nofile does not exist.
```

Comment: This helped me, I think some missed that the OP was asking about makefile.  I didn't understand why "&& echo -n yes" is necessary.  Explanation: if test -e returns 1 (not found) then shell won't execute the echo command, and therefore won't match the yes in ifeq

Comment: I think you understand it correctly in your explanation statement.

Comment: @BradDre -- The `echo -n yes` changes the success of `test` into the string `yes` without NL.  The `ifeq` can then compare it with the hard coded `yes`.  All because `ifeq` wants a string to compare to, not a success status from a shell command.

Comment: I had to remove the `-n` part to get it to work...

Answer (score 14):

Missing a semicolon

```sh
if [ -a myApp ];
then
  rm myApp
fi
```

However, I assume you are checking for existence before deletion to prevent an error message. If so, you can just use `rm -f myApp` which "forces" delete, i.e. doesn't error out if the file didn't exist.

Comment: ThHat's exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: this won't work in a Makefile because the if is still spread over multiple lines - you need to either put this on one line or use \es. and even if you added the \ es you are still missing some semi-colons.

Answer (score 5):

```Makefile
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(PATH_TO_FILE))","")
    FILE_EXISTS = 1
else
    FILE_EXISTS = 0
endif
```

This solution posted above works best. But make sure that you do not stringify the PATH_TO_FILE assignment
E.g.,

```Makefile
PATH_TO_FILE = "/usr/local/lib/libhl++.a" # WILL NOT WORK
```

It must be

```Makefile
PATH_TO_FILE = /usr/local/lib/libhl++.a
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers like the one from @mark-wilkins using \ to continue lines and ; to terminate them in the shell or like the ones from @kenorb changing this to one line are good and will fix this problem.

there's a simpler answer to the original problem (as @alexey-polonsky pointed out).  Use the -f flag to rm so that it won't trigger an error

```
rm -f myApp
```

this is simpler, faster and more reliable.  Just be careful not to end up with a slash and an empty variable

<strike>rm -f /$(myAppPath)</strike>   #NEVER DO THIS

you might end up deleting your system.

Comment: This is a good answer for deleting the file that the OP had, but I'm pretty sure most people who find this question aren't actually looking for deleting any files; this is actually evidenced by the fact that most answers don't even mention `rm` at all; BTW, I'm pretty sure that `rm -f /$(myAppPath)` won't do any damage, either, because `/` is a directory, and the `-r` is missing.

Comment: This is not a simpler solution. Like @cnst said, there may be reasons why the original poster does not simply want to do an `rm -f`, e.g. they may want to `rm` a variable.

Comment: I like this simple answer.  if the file exists delete, if it doesn't exist, don't complain!

Answer (score 1):

```
test ! -f README.md || echo 'Support OpenSource!' >> README.md
```

"If README.md does not exist, do nothing (and exit successfully). Otherwise, append text to the end."

If you use `&&` instead of `||` then you generate an error when the file doesn't exist:

```
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'dostuff' failed
make: *** [dostuff] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `test` command to check if the file exists or not and then use `rm` to delete it.\

Syntax for the file command is -

```sh
test -f FILENAME && echo exists || echo not exists
```

Syntax for deleting the file is -

```sh
rm -rf FILENAME
```

So now we need a command to delete the file only if it exists so we will only use OR `||` with the test command

```sh
test -f FILENAME || rm -rf FILENAME
```

use can use multiple commands by using and `&&` within the parenthesis `()`

```sh
test -f FILENAME || (rm -rf FILENAME && echo "file deleted as it exists")
```

Comment: This does not work in a makefile. It ill always run the `rm -rf FILENAME` regardless of the first `test` result

Answer (score 0):

I was trying:

```
[ -f $(PROGRAM) ] && cp -f $(PROGRAM) $(INSTALLDIR)
```

And the positive case worked but my ubuntu bash shell calls this TRUE and breaks on the copy:

```
[ -f  ] && cp -f  /home/user/proto/../bin/
cp: missing destination file operand after '/home/user/proto/../bin/'
```

After getting this error, I google how to check if a file exists in make, and this is the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from the question, but in case you have a variable containing a list of files which you want to delete you can do

```
targets: filename1 filename2

clean_targets:
    @$(foreach file, $(targets), test -f $(file) && rm -v $(file) || echo No $(file);)
```

The basically you loop over the filenames defined by the targets variable and check with 'test' if the target exists. If yes, delete the file, if not, report it is not there. The last check (reporting it is not there) is necessary because otherwise an error is raised in case there is no target at all

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to command above, but reputation :)

You can have multi-line commands in gnu make targets by adding the .ONESHELL:  directive:

```Makefile
all-in-one-shell:
    if [ -a MyApp ] ; then
        echo "here"
    fi

.ONESHELL: all-in-one-shell
```

This eliminates trying to come up with creative one-liners or backslash everything.

Comment: Beware! You can't limit the effects of `.ONESHELL:` to a single rule like this answer suggests. From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html): "If the .ONESHELL special target appears **anywhere in the makefile** then **all recipe lines for each target** will be provided to a single invocation of the shell" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

We can also take advantages from GNU Coreutils's `test` builtin ([manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html)), which means we can check file existence like this:

```
check_exist:
    test -f file && echo yes || echo no
```

or more neatly, like this:

```
check_exist:
    [ -f file ] && echo yes || echo no
```