# Error in Makefile during a simple check for existing file

Tags: makefile, syntax-error, file-exists

within a makefile I need to check if a file exists. Regarding to this [answer from holms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553352/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-makefile#20566812), I tried it in this way:

```
all:
    ifeq ("","$(wildcard testFile)")
       echo "File exists"
    else
       echo "File is missing"
    endif
```

Nevertheless I get this error:

```
ifeq ("","")
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Where is my mistake and how to interpret this syntax error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tabbed the make syntax lines, so make is passing them to your shell, get rid of the tabs (also reverse the conditional and remove the quotes)

```
all:
ifeq (,$(wildcard testFile))
    echo File is missing
else
    echo File exists
endif
```

Comment: Okay, thank you that helped. I understand, the `ifeq`statement is interpreted by `make`. But the lines with `echo` should have a tabulator because they needed to be passed to my shell, right?

Comment: Okay, your answer seems to show four spaces instead a tabulator, which could be just a stylistic issue of the stackExchanges editor.