# Can't check file existense in a makefile

Tags: makefile, file-exists

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566812/789186) for "How do I check if file exists in Makefile?" question, I decided to try. I have a file `tact1.pdf` in the same folder with the makefile.

Code:

```
FILE = 'tact1.pdf'
all:
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(FILE))","")
    @echo "File exists"
else
    @echo "No file"
endif
```

Output:

```
$ make
No file
```

I tried the full path to the file: same result. What's wrong? OS: Windows XP, using cygwin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the quotes around the filename. They might be okay in bash or perl, but in a makefile, they are considered the first and  last characters of the filename.

`FILE = tact1.pdf`