# Using a conditional directive in Makefile

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements

I am struggling with a simple Makefile.

The simplified version looks something like this:

```
all : data/file1.RData

data/file1.RData : scripts/file1.R
  Rscript $<
```

I would like to execute the target of `scripts/file1.R` only when there is no file called `data/file1.RData` and I thought that the [Syntax of Conditionals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html#Conditional-Syntax) would be able to help me reach that goal.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553352/how-do-i-check-if-file-exists-in-makefile-so-i-can-delete-it), I noticed constructions that looked something like:

```
target :
ifeq (...)
    ...
endif
```

But my lack of understanding of the syntax of Makefiles inhibits the translation to my use case.
How do I perform this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to not use `ifeq` for this; that will run while the makefile is being parsed.  You probably want to not make this check until you are ready to run the rule.

A simple way to do it is with the `$(if ...)` function.  Something like this will work:

```
data/file1.RData : scripts/file1.R
        $(if $(wildcard $@),,Rscript $<)
```

I should point out that the `RData` file will always be considered (by make) to be out of date once `scripts/file1.R` is updated, since it never gets updated once it's created.

Documentation is available for the [wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html):

> The argument pattern is a file name pattern, typically containing wildcard characters (as in shell file name patterns). The result of wildcard is a space-separated list of the names of existing files that match the pattern.

(so, if the pattern, in this case just a simple filename, doesn't match an existing file the result is the empty string).

And the [if function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html):

> The first argument, condition, first has all preceding and trailing whitespace stripped, then is expanded. If it expands to any non-empty string, then the condition is considered to be true. If it expands to an empty string, the condition is considered to be false.

> If the condition is true then the second argument, then-part, is evaluated and this is used as the result of the evaluation of the entire if function.

> If the condition is false then the third argument, else-part, is evaluated and this is the result of the if function. If there is no third argument, the if function evaluates to nothing (the empty string).